# Differentiation of implicit function

Tags: derivatives

Whereas  $(\frac{x}{x+1})^2 + (\frac{y}{y+1})^2$ can be simplified by expanding and balancing the left and right sides into $x^2 \cdot y^2$ $= 4xy +2y +2x +1$, after implicit differentiation, the former gives derivative as $\frac{-(x( y+1)^3}{y(x+1)^3}$ the latter gives $\frac{-(2y -x \cdot y^2 +1)}{(x^2 \cdot y -2x -1)}$ which are not equal to each other. What went wrong?

thanks a lot

Comment: Is this a *Mathematica* question?

Comment: the first expression is not an implicit function, how can you get a derivative of it?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing went wrong. What you observed is normal.

Do not confuse equation and functions : Given two different functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, *their derivatives are not equal*.

In writing the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ one doesn't state that the functions are equal for any $x$, but that they are equal only for particular value(s) of $x$, so called roots.

So, you observe that $f(x_1)=g(x_1)$ if $x_1$ is a root of the equation. But in general $f'(x_1)\neq g'(x_1)$ since the derivatives of two different functions are different.